# How to execute string as a function using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have these two functions defined:

```
function fetchYPosts() {
    $http.get("/postsY/")
    .then(function(response) {
        self.posts = response.data;
    }, function(response) {
        self.posts = {};
    }); 
};
function fetchXPosts() {
    $http.get("/postsX/")
    .then(function(response) {
        self.posts = response.data;
    }, function(response) {
        self.posts = {};
    }); 
};
```

I am passed an `id` and a string ('X' or 'Y' is what I want the end-user to pass to me) from the front-end. I have this code which handles when the string is passed:

```
self.handler = function(id, XOrY) {
    $http.post("/" + XOrY + "/" + id + "/handle/")
    .then(function(response) {
        functionToCall = "fetch" + XOrY + "Posts()";
        # Here is where I want to call funcitonToCall.
    }, function(response) {
        self.cerrorMessages = BaseService.accessErrors(response.data);
    });
};
```

With that said, given a variable which holds a string, how do I call the function which has the name of the string variable?

Comment: Looks like an XY problem. Why exactly do you want to do this?

Comment: @elclanrs I have two objects on the front-end (XPosts and YPosts). Each post has a button. The button should post to the URL `/{{X or Y}}/id/handle` and then call `fetch{{ XorY }}()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should select the correct method using something like this:

```
var fetcher = XOrY == 'x' ? fetchXPosts : fetchYPosts;
```

which can be used like:

```
self.handler = function(id, XOrY) {
    var fetcher = XOrY == 'x' ? fetchXPosts : fetchYPosts;
    $http.post("/" + XOrY + "/" + id + "/handle/")
    .then(function(response) {
        fetcher();
        # Here is where I want to call funcitonToCall.
    }, function(response) {
        self.cerrorMessages = BaseService.accessErrors(response.data);
    });
};
```

If you have a situation where there's just too many different fetching functions, you can instead define them like this as part of a hash:

```
var fetch = {

  YPosts: function() {
    $http.get("/postsY/")
    .then(function(response) {
        self.posts = response.data;
    }, function(response) {
        self.posts = {};
    }); 
  },

  XPosts: function() {
    $http.get("/postsX/")
    .then(function(response) {
        self.posts = response.data;
    }, function(response) {
        self.posts = {};
    }); 
  }

}
```

and grab the function from `fetch[XorY]`:

```
self.handler = function(id, XOrY) {
    $http.post("/" + XOrY + "/" + id + "/handle/")
    .then(function(response) {
        fetch[XorY]();
        # Here is where I want to call funcitonToCall.
    }, function(response) {
        self.cerrorMessages = BaseService.accessErrors(response.data);
    });
};
```

Comment: I used the second way you provided because it looks cleaner and more resuable. I am noticing a difference in speed for some reason (it's noticeably slower doing `fetch[XOrY]()` than `fetchPosts()`) but other than that, it's good.

Answer (score 1):

you can encapsule these two function in an object, and call this service in your method like this

```
   var service = {
     fetchXPosts: function(){},
     fetchYPosts： function(){}
   }

    self.handler = function(id, XORY) {
       service['fetch'+XORY+'posts']();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. Just to verify, what exactly does `.call(service, id);` do? Wouldn't `service['fetch'+XORY+'posts']` be sufficient, given that my `fetchXPosts` and `fetchYPosts` functions do not require the `id` parameter?

Comment: ok, then you don't need call, you can just use `service['fetch+'XORY'+posts']()` to execute function, call will be used when you want to bind the `this` context of function.